# Someone who takes credit for others work

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for someone who takes credit for other people's work?

Comment: [Plagiarist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plagiarist) (noun): One who illicitly reproduces the artistic work, for example, of another.

Comment: Also: fraud, charlatan, impostor, stealer, plagiarizer.

Comment: Sounds exactly like a politician.

Answer (score 1):

**Plagiarist** is obvious, and perhaps a bit too obvious, i.e. almost, but not entirely, what you're looking for.

**Cryptomnesiac** is wittier and more to the point (in some cases). It would imply that the thief has no memory of actually stealing someone else's work and assumes that it is his own.

Here's a [Wiki article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptomnesia)

Comment: @user116032: You've got a point. We're looking for something with leech-like qualities, yet nearly the exact opposite of sycophant.